# Take an action on first or last click of repeatButton

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I specify an action on the first or last click of a `RepeatButton`?

Example:

A label is initially set to 0

While `RepeatButton`is pressed, value is incremented continuously

When `RepeatButton`is left, the value resets to 0

alternatively, set the counter to 0 immediately when the button is pressed, and start incrementing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't need to use a `RepeatButton` to do what you want. Instead, it would be better to use a standard `Button` and to handle the `PreviewMouseDown` and `PreviewMouseUp` events. Try something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Content="Press and Hold" PreviewMouseDown="Button_PreviewMouseDown" 
        PreviewMouseUp="Button_PreviewMouseUp" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding YourValue}" />
</Grid>
```

...

```
private DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();

private void Button_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100);
    timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    timer.Start();
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    YourValue++;
}

private void Button_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
}
```

You can adjust the number of milliseconds between the value increments to suit your requirements.